# Office 365 Protected View Breaking Excel Marcos

Tags: vba, excel, office365

Our client has updated to Microsoft Office 365 (Version 1708) and when receiving a generated Excel file (xlt) via email which contains a vb macro, it now displays "PROTECTED VIEW Be careful - email attachments can contain viruses. Unless you need to edit, it's safer to stay in Protected View." - and doesn't run the macro (of course).

Clicking the "Enable Editing" the user gets a runtime error, but in Office 2013 it works fine.

Also in Office 365 if we untick "Enable Protected View for Outlook attachments" and resend the file, it works okay.

Any ideas?
Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Sorry, we are only talking about one version of 365 (v1708), on Office 2013 the file works correctly.

Comment: have you checked the Trust Center settings: Macro settings + Programmatic access?

Comment: In the Trust Center, the Marco Settings is set to "Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)", actually the whole Macro Settings is disabled and I have also ticked "Trust access to the VBA project object model" without success. How would you go about programmatic access?

Comment: In the Programmatic Access options, I remember we had a problem once when MS Office did not recognise the Antivirus. I don't think you have to change anything there. What about the Email Security settings? Scripts allowed to be run? What about the File Block settings in your client's Excel?

Comment: I cant see Programmatic Access option in the Excel's Trust Center, I can see it in Outlook's Trust Center though. In Excel, if we untick "Enable Protected View for Outlook attachments" and resend the file, it works okay - but the client would not want that option.

Comment: Well, I could not think of anything else. Any chance your client would work around, maybe on one machine only and re-distribute the file internally then? Sorry...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of hacking and googling, we found that this is an existing bug in Office 365.

A workable workaround for us was to change:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call formatData
End Sub
```

To:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call formatData
End Sub
```